# Doubts on javascript ,css, ssh, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. From what I gather http and ssh are two protocols independent of one another. Are there any particular situations  where can we use SSH for making http requests to a web server ?
2. As I understand CSS and javascript can be added to HTML code to enable style and animations to the html page.
   But can styling be done to some extent using html itself without implementing CSS? Also, is the same possible with animations too?
3. CSS can modify html output by implementing styling on html  content. But is the same possible vice-versa? Can HTML modify CSS?.
4. This question may not directly relate to Javascript but in general does setting up slave db help when database becomes too large to keep in one system.

Comment: Welcome. Your question's title is discouraging (vague and broad), your first question shows lack of research. Your second question has the same problem as the first one. So I am not going to read the rest. Please, read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: 1 - no, why. 2 - limited, no. 3 - css applies style to HTML, so the inverse makes no sense. 4 - too broad

Comment: Feel free to visit this link for much help about what to ask here and how. - https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

1) 
Any application that makes an interaction to the www, may use HTTP to create its request packets and then pass them to the transport layer of the client system.
SSH on the other hand (said to be a replacement of Telnet) is used for running commands over a remote server. 
Both can't be used together IMO.

2)
CSS provides a way to create reusable style classes for html components. What is achieved using CSS can be achieved using HTML as well, CSS just makes it more cleaner and modular.

3)
HTML in itself is a static way to do things, what makes it dynamic is javascript which introduces DOM manipulation on the client side. javascript by exposing document.stylesheets, can surely manipulate CSS. HTML alone can't.